# On log in to Magento 2.1 admin I get (LogicException): Could not create an acl object

Tags: magento-2.1, acl

On login to Magento 2.1 admin I get following error .

```
   1 exception(s):

    Exception #0 (LogicException): Could not create an acl object: Invalid Document 
    Element 'admin': This element is not expected. Expected is ( resource ).
    Line: 5


    Exception #0 (LogicException): Could not create an acl object: Invalid Document 
    Element 'admin': This element is not expected. Expected is ( resource ).
    Line: 5   

    #0 /var/www/html/Dir/var/generation/Magento/Framework/Acl/Builder/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\Acl\Builder->getAcl()
#1 /var/www/html/Dir/vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Auth/Session.php(221): Magento\Framework\Acl\Builder\Proxy->getAcl()
#2 /var/www/html/Dir/var/generation/Magento/Backend/Model/Auth/Session/Interceptor.php(102): Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session->processLogin()
#3 /var/www/html/Dir/vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Auth.php(156): Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session\Interceptor->processLogin()
#4 /var/www/html/Dir/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146): Magento\Backend\Model\Auth->login('*****', '*****')
#5 /var/www/html/Dir/var/generation/Magento/Backend/Model/Auth/Interceptor.php(78): Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Interceptor->___callPlugins('login', Array, Array)
#6 /var/www/html/Dir/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(205): Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Interceptor->login('*****', '*****')
#7 /var/www/html/Dir/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(157): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->_performLogin(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#8 /var/www/html/Dir/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(125): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->_processNotLoggedInUser(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#9 /var/www/html/Dir/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#10 /var/www/html/Dir/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Backend...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor), Array, 'adminMassaction...')
#11 /var/www/html/Dir/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/MassactionKey.php(33): Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#12 /var/www/html/Dir/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\MassactionKey->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#13 /var/www/html/Dir/var/generation/Magento/Backend/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Index/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#14 /var/www/html/Dir/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#15 /var/www/html/Dir/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#16 /var/www/html/Dir/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#17 /var/www/html/Dir/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install')
#18 /var/www/html/Dir/vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#19 /var/www/html/Dir/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#20 /var/www/html/Dir/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#21 /var/www/html/Dir/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#22 /var/www/html/Dir/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#23 /var/www/html/Dir/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#24 {main}
```

How to debug it and find the root cause that is which acl file is creating this issue?

Comment: this seems like an external module failure, having an invalid etc/acl.xml file

Comment: @DavidVerholen  Do you know how can I debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the following approach to debug this issue.

1) By reading the line *Could not create an acl object* I know its ACL related issue.

2) By reading  *Element 'admin': This element is not expected. Expected is ( resource ).* its known that the issue is with element admin

3) *Line: 5* Indicate that the issue is in line 5 of an ACL file.

4) So I searched in all the *acl.xml* files for the element admin.

I found it in an *acl.xml* file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>      <!-- This is line 5 and element is admin. This is Magento 1 way -->
                <children>
                    <epicor_common module="epicor_common">
                        <children>
                            <elements>
                                <title>Elements</title>
                                <children>
                                    <elements_transaction>
                                        <title>Transaction</title>
                                    </elements_transaction>
                                </children>
                            </elements>
                        </children>
                    </epicor_common>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

After fixing the acl.xml file it worked for me. Syntax of Magento1 ACL and Magento2 ACL is different.

Comment: How did you solved this error? Why is admin element problematic?

Comment: @BlueDev <admin>  node is wrong in Magento 2

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my custom plugin and solved it. So just want to share how I solved it if anyone gets the same issue.

This was my error after logging in into admin dashboard:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (LogicException): Could not create an acl object: The XML in file "/home/magento2/app/code/Mycustommodule/Mymodulejs/etc/acl.xml" is invalid:
Element 'admin': This element is not expected. Expected is ( resource ).
Line: 5

Verify the XML and try again.

Exception #0 (LogicException): Could not create an acl object: The XML in file "/home/magento2/app/code/Mycustommodule/Mymodulejs/etc/acl.xml" is invalid:
Element 'admin': This element is not expected. Expected is ( resource ).
Line: 5

Verify the XML and try again.
#0 /home/magento2/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Acl/Builder/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\Acl\Builder->getAcl()
#1 /home/magento2/app/code/Magento/Backend/Model/Auth/Session.php(227): Magento\Framework\Acl\Builder\Proxy->getAcl()
#2 /home/magento2/app/code/Magento/Backend/Model/Auth.php(165): Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session->processLogin()
#3 /home/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Backend\Model\Auth->login('admin', '0omochl@1WA')
#4 /home/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Interceptor->___callParent('login', Array)
#5 /home/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}('admin', '0omochl@1WA')
#6 /home/magento2/generated/code/Magento/Backend/Model/Auth/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Interceptor->___callPlugins('login', Array, Array)
#7 /home/magento2/app/code/Magento/Backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(205): Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Interceptor->login('admin', '0omochl@1WA')
#8 /home/magento2/app/code/Magento/Backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(157): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->_performLogin(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#9 /home/magento2/app/code/Magento/Backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(125): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->_processNotLoggedInUser(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#10 /home/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#11 /home/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#12 /home/magento2/generated/code/Magento/Backend/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Index/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, NULL)
#13 /home/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController.php(159): Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#14 /home/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController.php(99): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http), Object(Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor))
#15 /home/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#16 /home/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#17 /home/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#18 /home/magento2/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#19 /home/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#20 /home/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#21 /home/magento2/pub/index.php(37): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#22 {main}
```

Problematic acl.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <mycustommodule translate="title" module="Mycustommodule_Mymodulejs">
                                        <title>MyModule.js Options</title>
                                        <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                                    </mycustommodule>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

Then I've just modified it to:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores">
                    <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores_settings">
                        <resource id="Magento_Config::config">
                            <resource id="Mycustommodule_Mymodulejs::modulejs" title="MyModule.js Options" sortOrder="1" />
                        </resource>
                    </resource>
                </resource>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

So on the end, it seems that the problem is that I was using an old AccessControlLists (acl.xml) structure from Magento 1 which is changed in Magento 2 and not accepted.

More info here in Mageplaza documentation - [Magento 2 Admin ACL Access Control Lists](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-acl-access-control-lists.html)